# How to program a browser integration with an external editor like MS Word in Java?

Tags: java, web-applications, browser, editor

You may all have seen online content management systems or publishing platforms, where one can edit a page, but for convenience, the editing is not done in the browser, but instead in Microsoft Word. So whenever you open the page to edit it, the current page is send to MS Word and after completing the editing, Word sends back the page to the server.

A good example is Confluence. Instead of using the built-in WYSIWYG editor, you can also edit a page in MS Word.

How does this work technically? I want to program something similar on a Java servlet based web app. The first part is easy. I convert my page into the format of the external application and send it to the browser setting the correct mimetype. The external application will open the document. But I have no idea how the second part works. How does this application sends the file back?

Please send me any pointers you might have. My main problem is probably that I really don't know what I should search for. Also, if you know any opensource Java based projects doing something similar, I would like to study them to get started.

PS: Please feel free to change the title of this question!

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want to change the desktop application (like MS Word) to interface with my web app. Instead, I expect this can somehow be solved with sending the file to a temporary location and maybe using some JavaScript magic to get it back from the browser to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this works is if you start Microsoft Word not wih a file as an argument, but witha n http/https URL that points to a WebDAV-supporting location. In this case Word will send the file bach witha PUT method when saving.